# How to index model association in Tire(retire)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

Hi I am using retire and elasticsearch in a rails project to index my users and an additional model special_codes.  My goal is to add an index to my Users model so that I when I search on Users the new index(special_code) will provide hits.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  has_one :specialcode

  after_create :generate_specialcode

  mapping do
    indexes :email, :type => 'string'
    indexes :specialcode do 
      indexes :code, :type => 'string'
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json( include: { specialcode: {only: [:code]} })
  end

  private

  def generate_specialcode
    Specialcode.create(code: 'derp', user_id: self.id)
    self.tire.update_index #not really needed(see after_save), just here for example.
  end
end

class Specialcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  belongs_to :user

  after_save :update_user_index

  private

  def update_user_index
    self.user.tire.update_index
  end
end
```

I'd like to see `User.search('derp')` bring back a user hit because I've indexed the special code in with the user.  I've tried quite a bit with mappings and updating indexes without getting any hits.  The example above hopefully provides a base to work from.  Thanks

## Update

I found the solution with the help of Bruce.  I've added `mapping`, `to_indexed_json`, and `update_user_index` to the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have to_indexed_json and mappings in User model already? Try use after_touch callback to update index in user.

Comment: Bruce thanks for your reply.  It got the brain juices flowing again.  My to_indexed_json wasn't correct.  I stumbled upon my mistake in this [thread](https://github.com/karmi/retire/issues/898).  I'll update my code above to reflect the fix.